# result of an array as a filter in get-adcomputer

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to consult the security event log of a windows server 2008 machine to find out from which computer users are trying to connect 
because there are accounts that are blocked and I do not know since the PC does it.

The case is that this script does a little what I need, but it gives me the `SID` of the machine and its name.
How do I pass the `$SID_PC` variable so that the `Get-AdComputer` works and gives me the name and not the computer's `SID`?

```
 $fecha = get-date -format yyyy-MMMM-mm
 $logfile = "Control_eventos_seguridad_$fecha.txt"
 #conectar con los visores de eventos de los DC's
 $DC = "MI_DC"

 write-host "Recuperando eventos de $DC..."
 $lockoutevents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $DC -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';Id=4771} -erroraction silentlycontinue
 if ($lockoutevents -ne $null)
 {
  foreach ($event in $lockoutevents)
  {
   $cuando = get-date($Event.TimeCreated) -uformat "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
   $quien = $event.Properties[0].Value
   $SID_PC = $Event.Properties[1].Value
   $donde = get-ADComputer -Filter {SID -like "$SID_PC"} -Properties * | Select-Object Name
   out-file $logfile -input "$cuando $quien $donde" -append
  }#fin foreach events
 }#fin if events not null

 #limpio el log de eventos repetidos
 $cleanlogfile = get-content($logfile) | select -unique
 $cleanlogfile | out-file $logfile
```

Comment: _that are blocked and I do not know since the PC does it_ Hm?

Comment: _result of an array as a filter in get-adcomputer_ Is definitely not what you are asking. You are askin a thing like _How do I get a computer name by it's SID with `Get-AdComputer?`_ Or _How to `Where-Object` with an array of values_ I found it hard to get the context of the question's title and its content

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity $SID_PC | Select-Object Name
```

Get-ADComputer identity parameter accepts SID

Check Identity parameter description
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx

Comment: Hi, if I saw those options you comment, thank you.
But the problem persists, it might be the kind of output I'm using; type of data that can not be used as a variable if it is not treated in any way.
Or how can I make a few quotation marks appear for the value that evaluates the liki?

Answer (score 0):

if I saw those options you comment, thank you.
But the problem persists, it might be the kind of output I'm using; type of data that can not be used as a variable if it is not treated in any way.
Or how can I make a few quotation marks appear for the value that evaluates the liki?